# relation does not exist when deploying django app to Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django/postgres app to Heroku and running into an error when running this command:

```
(menv)Nitins-MacBook-Air:lists Nitin$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free.
(menv)Nitins-MacBook-Air:lists Nitin$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.9322
 !    
 !    Error connecting to dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process
```

When I then launch my heroku site, I receive this browser error:

```
ProgrammingError at /movies/
relation "movies_movie" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT('*') AS "__count" FROM "movies_movie"
```

I initially thought there was an issue with the Heroku database, but after creating a new one, I'm seeing the same error. Locally, however, with my local database settings, my site loads successfully with 'foreman start'.

So something doesn't add up for me. Any ideas?

Comment: have you run migrations on heroku ?

Comment: Yep, I unsuccessfully attempted to migrate my local postgres data to heroku. That attempt must have broken something. What does that mean?

Comment: I think you should check your database setting again, whihc database you are using on heroku

Comment: Why are you running `syncdb` rather than `migrate`?

Comment: I was kind of blindly following some posts I found, including this from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#syncing-the-database

Answer (score 1):

You can try recreating the full database if there is no data present.

Heroku gives you a Postgres database by default. To completely remove it run:

```
heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql:dev
```

Now create new one with:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:dev
```

Comment: What do I replace "heroku-postgesql:dev" in your add/create command? I assume this names the new database that I'm creating.

Comment: yes its the default database name provided by heroku

Comment: Got it. The 'create' command worked, but for 'destroy', I had to insert the existing database name. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Same issue when trying to syncdb.

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the project/app and copying over the files I needed. It ended up working, but I'm still not sure what went wrong initially.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Ajay solution. I ended up solving the issue with resetting the whole Database.
From Heroku web dashboard, chose *Databases* then chose my database in that page and then under settings button *Reset Database...*

Just in case, you can back up database from web interface as well before deleting everything.